# Dynamic sql with CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

```
   SET @SQL =
        'SELECT
        CaseStatus =
            CASE Level1Status
                WHEN 1100 THEN ''Case Submitted to QC''
                WHEN 1200 THEN ''Pending QC''
                WHEN 1400 THEN ''Passed QC''
            
            END,
```

I'm currently having problems with the dynamic sql/case expression above , as I can't seem to put strings inside dynamic sql, does anyone happen to have a solution to fixing this

**EDIT**

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)

```
SET @SQL =
    'SELECT
    CaseStatus =
        CASE Level1Status
            WHEN 1100 THEN ''Case Submitted to QC''
            WHEN 1200 THEN ''Pending QC''
            WHEN 1400 THEN ''Passed QC''
        
        END,
        
        CaseStartDateTime,
        CaseEndDateTime,
        StatusName,
        Cell_NameDescription,
        QCAnalystName,
        AnalystName,
        Upload_Datetime,
        Requesting_Entity,
        Legal_Entity_TypeDescription,
        HighPriorityDescription,
        DD_Level_RequiredDescription,
        CountryDscr,
        Maintable.KYCCaseId AS KYCCaseId
    FROM
        UACTc75760ab10784b51b585f082d4b25223 AS MI,
        UACT175e55161660402692a53a4cdeb89bd6 AS MainTable,
        UACT5996d6e5151245cab24e4e76e3e53540 AS Statuses,
        UACTde5f05df6c5f4872a1e57b3cf8368301 AS AddressDetails
    WHERE
        (
        MI.CaseStartDateTime BETWEEN ' + quotename(convert(varchar(10), @CaseStartDateTime, 120), '''') + ' AND '  + quotename(convert(varchar(10), @CaseEndDateTime, 120), '''') +
        ' OR
        MI.CaseEndDateTime BETWEEN ' + quotename(convert(varchar(10), @CaseStartDateTime, 120), '''') +  ' AND ' + quotename(convert(varchar(10), @CaseEndDateTime, 120), '''') +
        ' )
    AND
        MI.KYCCase_Id = MainTable.KYCCaseId'
    IF @StatusName IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@StatusName)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
        AND
            Statuses.SourceStatus = MainTable.Level1Status
        AND
            Statuses.StatusName = ' + quotename(@StatusName, '''')
    IF @CountryDscr IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@CountryDscr)) != N''
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        AND
            AddressDetails.CountryDscr = ' + quotename(@CountryDscr, '''')      
    IF @CellDscr IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@CellDscr)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' 
        AND
            MainTable.Cell_NameDescription = ' + quotename(@CellDscr, '''') 
    IF @QCAnalystName IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@QCAnalystName)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        AND
            MainTable.QCAnalystName = ' + quotename(@QCAnalystName, '''')   
    IF @AnalystName IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@AnalystName)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        AND
            MainTable.AnalystName = ' + quotename(@AnalystName, '''')
    IF @RequestingEntity IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@RequestingEntity)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        AND
            MainTable.Requesting_Entity = ' + quotename(@RequestingEntity, '''')
    IF @EntityType IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@EntityType)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        AND
            MainTable.Legal_Entity_TypeDescription = ' + quotename(@EntityType, '''')
    IF @HighPriority IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@HighPriority)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        AND
            MainTable.HighPriorityDescription = ' + quotename(@HighPriority, '''')
    IF @DDLevelRequired IS NOT NULL AND ltrim(rtrim(@DDLevelRequired)) != N''
        SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        AND
            MainTable.DD_Level_RequiredDescription = ' + quotename(@DDLevelRequired, '''')  

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

This is the entire code, The error I'm getting is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'.

Comment: Please clarify the query so we have some idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to create a filter for a report where if a status is 1100, 1200 and 1400 a column is added to the table to reflect the strings 'Case Submitted', 'Pending QC' and 'Passed QC', the problem is that because my dynamic sql is currently set to the variable @SQL as a string ,i am can't add the strings 'Case Submitted', 'Pending QC' and 'Passed QC' to the case statement

Thanks

Comment: @EmperorDev its working fine using dynamic sql  with your code also .

Comment: I don't think that is your problem. What error are you getting exactly? Can you show us the rest of your code as this certainly isn't all of it.

Comment: @EmperorDev, you have correct statement. You can see that with `print @sql`.

Comment: What are you passing into the parameters? It's hard to know what's going wrong here without an idea of the data going in. Have you tried running the query normally and replacing the parameters with hard coded values? Also can you try change your @SQL to nvarchar(max) to see if that helps? You may be using more than 4000 characters

Comment: Case EXPRESSION, not case statement...

Comment: @EmperorDev, just do `PRINT @SQL` instead of `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL`. You will see actual constructed query. Try to execute it manually/ If errors you probably see where you are concatenating with errors. Correct and try again...  You are quoting everything... dates, strings, numerics. When you are quoting the result will be get by engine as some column name or some other object name. Play around with print.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine .

```
Create Table #Level1Status(Id int identity ,Level1Status int)

Insert INto #Level1Status(Level1Status) values(1100),(1200),(1400)


            Declare @SQL Nvarchar(Max)
            SET @SQL =
                    'SELECT 
                    CaseStatus =
                        CASE Level1Status
                            WHEN 1100 THEN ''Case Submitted to QC''
                            WHEN 1200 THEN ''Pending QC''
                            WHEN 1400 THEN ''Passed QC''

                        END from #Level1Status';
            Exec SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concatenate your @SQL string with local variable "@xxx", in case any of thease may null, It want give any output so use ISNULL() or COALESCE() at concatenation with all local vaiable you used.